# Deploy Nodejs app on google kubernetes engine using Docker and PM2

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, gcloud, pm2

I've a Nodejs app and using Babel to enable ES6 features. I can run it on local system in dev mode. I want to deploy it to Kubernetes using PM2.

It is giving an error when I try to run it with PM2 using process.json.

```
/bin/bash:1
15:59:52 23|app   | (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ����
15:59:52 23|app   |                                                               ^
15:59:52 23|app   | SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
15:59:52 23|app   |     at new Script (vm.js:85:7)
15:59:52 23|app   |     at createScript (vm.js:266:10)
15:59:52 23|app   |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:314:10)
15:59:52 23|app   |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:28)
15:59:52 23|app   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
15:59:52 23|app   |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
15:59:52 23|app   |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
15:59:52 23|app   |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
```

This is my process.json

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "script": "./dist/bin/www.js --env production",
            "exec_mode": "cluster",
            "instances": 0,
            "max_restarts": 20,
      "env": {
          "NODE_ENV": "production"
      },
      "env_production": {
          "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run this command `pm2 ./dist/bin/www.js --env production` it works fine but when I try to run it using process.json like `pm2 start process.json --no-daemon` it throws the above error.

I'm trying it on local system but it also happens when I deploy to gcloud using a Dockerfile with `kubectl`

Can someone point me to the right direction where I should try to look.

Comment: I have run into issues like this multiple times and every time it was related to my build process not properly set up, i.e. not all of the files were transpiled.  I've also had issues where my imports were incorrect for my config files and this caused issues only when they were built.  I would check to make sure everything is copied over properly to your dist folder.  I would check the actually built files and see what is going on with them.  Most likely you have a transpiled file that is including a non-transpiled file.  So sift through the built files and see what you go going on there.

Comment: @Rami I'll go through it again but my built file is working just fine. I've tried running `node ./dist/bin/www.js` which output file after the build is done using Babel and this works just fine. Don't you think if it was a problem with build then this should through an error?

Comment: Well you might have some code in your app that does things dynamically. For example you could have code check for production environment and if true find a certain file and that file is there locally but when you build and push to server that file isn't there or only the TS version of it is there.

Comment: Try building and running locally but before you run it delete your app folder  or something and see what happens. Try things like that until you can recreate it, also try to recreate it with Docker and PM2 locally

Comment: @Rami Thank you for responding. I'm not using TS, I'm using Babel for ES6 features. I've all my JS code in /src and then transpile the whole directory to /dist.
I'm running it using PM2 locally and it is throwing the mentioned error. I haven't tried with Docker, as I'm not good with cloud stuff.

Comment: did you try to remove the --no-daemon flag?

Comment: Yes, I did on local system.

Comment: any chance you can share the source code so I can attempt to recreate this issue?

Comment: remove the --env production from your script.  That shouldn't be necessary as you're already defining the NODE_ENV

Comment: I'll share code repo with you

Answer (score 1):

try this process.json:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "script": "./dist/bin/www.js",
            "exec_mode": "cluster",
            "instances": 0,
            "max_restarts": 20,
      "env": {
          "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "env_production": {
          "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
        }
    ]
}
```

CLI:

```
pm2 start process.json --no-daemon --env production
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck. You can try if possible with this repo. 
https://github.com/tahirwaseer/test-node

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out